# $ |T z|= |z| \,\,\forall z\in \mathbb{C} \implies ab=0 $

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers

If $T: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is given by $ T(z)= a z + b \bar z$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$.

Then is it true that, $ |T z|= |z| \,\,\forall z\in \mathbb{C} \implies ab=0 $ ?

If yes, how can I show this?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd consider $|Tz|^2=(Tz)(\overline{T(z)})$.

Comment: Yeah..I tried with this..but was messed up.

Comment: How about considering that $|ae^{it}+be^{-it}|^2=1$?

Comment: If $a,b$ are both real numebrs, this is easy: take $z=1$ and $z=i$, and square both equations. Are $a,b$ real numebrs or complex numbers ?

Comment: Complex numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$T:$ $\mathbb{C}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{C}$ by $T(z)=\lambda z + \mu \bar{z}$ for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555737/t-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-by-tz-lambda-z-mu-barz-for-every) – found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24T(z)%3D%20a%20z%20%2B%20b%20%5Cbar%20z%24%2C%20%24%7CT(z)%7C%20%3D%20%7Cz%7C%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note
\begin{align*}
|Tz|^2 &= (Tz) \overline{T(z)}\\
&= (az+b \bar z) (\bar a \bar z + \bar b z)\\
&= |a|^2 z \bar z + |b|^2 z \bar z + a \bar b z^2 + \bar a b \bar z^2)\\
&= (|a|^2+|b|^2) |z| + (a \bar b z^2) + \overline{(a \bar b z^2)}\\
&= (|a|^2+|b|^2) |z| + 2 \text{Re}(a \bar b z^2).\\
\end{align*}
If $a \bar b \neq 0$, then we can vary $z$ while keeping $|z|$ constant, and $|Tz|^2$ will change due to the $\text{Re($a \bar b z^2$)}$ term, but $|z|^2$ will not, a contradiction. So $a \bar b = 0$, giving either $a=0$ or $\bar b = 0$. The result follows.

Comment: $a,b$ are not supposed to be real numbers...

Comment: My bad, I've fixed my mistake now.

Comment: Is there any typo with $ |z|^2$

Comment: +1 for this elegant answer.